# How to create mobile size emulator in Android 3.0?

Tags: java, android

If i create the emulator for Android 3.0, it opens for tablet size. Is it possible to create emulator for mobile in Android 3.0?

Comment: Android 3.0 is a tablet operating system.

Comment: Ok. but we developing app for mobile device in Android 3.0 i am testing the app in Android 4.0 emulator.

Comment: see this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot, Android 3.0 aka HoneyComb was intended purely as a tablet operating system. From 4.0 onwards i.e. ICS which could support extra large screens (tablets) to phones as well. So if you wish to develop applications for phone, then either use 2.3.3 or 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Android Virtual Device Manager in Eclipse .Click on New and specify your target .Once you have created an AVD with required specifications.Select it in AVD Manager and click on Start ,this should launch your AVD.Now try installing your app on running AVD.

Comment: I am not asking how to create AVD? First understand my question ok?

Answer (score 0):

In New Developer Tools (r21) they given many definitions in `AVD Manager`